# A peekaboo bug in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, haslayout

Okay, I'm baffled.

IE9 is displaying inconsistent page width issues on some but not all pages of a site under development.

In IE9: Going to http://sistercarmen.org/cms/ you can see what looks ROUGHLY like the right page. Actually the page is slightly too wide, and that is certainly a problem. But nothing like what's happening on the [About](http://sistercarmen.org/cms/about/) page or the [History](http://sistercarmen.org/cms/about/history/) page.

On those pages, the page gets very wide indeed. BUT, if you mouse over a link in the right column (likely need to horizontally scroll to see one) the page snaps back to the correct size.

Building a [simplified test page @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKDNn/), I could confirm that this seems to be related to `display: table` but that is important to me so I can serve up the Nav later in the source code. An [even simpler test page](http://jeremycarlson.com/test/beforecaption3.html) shows that `display:table` generally works for IE9.

So ... **Is this a hasLayout issue, and if so, how can I force hasLayout in IE9?**

Thank you very much,

Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that is odd. For what it's worth, you page works fine in IE10.

I've not been able to find a proper solution for you in the time I have available, but in the meanwhile, have you considered applying a `width` or a `max-width` to the body text element?

[EDIT]

I can confirm that adding `width:100%` to the `content-lead` element will work around the problem.

Still not an answer to why the problem is occurring, but at least it's a work-around.

[EDIT again]

Actually, it turns out the above work-around isn't quite as good as I originally thought. The `width:100%` only worked for me because I was playing in the console. Doing it in CSS has no effect.

Setting a fixed width may help, or possibly using CSS `calc()` if a completely fixed width isn't suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm not getting the results you are. I just tried adding `width:100%` to `.content-lead`, `.entry-content`, `#content`, on my local machine—still seeing the bug.

Comment: hmm, it worked for me... I started by adding `max-width:560px` to `content-lead`, then changed it to `width:560px`, and then to `width:100%`. It worked fine for me all along. But I'll have another go, see what I can see.

Comment: hehe. Yep, you're right -- going straight to `width:100%` doesn't do it. It needed me to be playing with fixed widths first. *-sigh-*

Comment: Your question, though, is a good one. I might just pursue fixed widths via media queries. Not sure I have a better option.

Comment: if your page width is fixed, just use a fixed pixel with. If your page width is flexible then a fixed width isn't going to be much use, but IE9 supports CSS `calc()`, so you could try using `calc(100% - 350px)` (or whatever the width of the side panel is).

Comment: @Spudley your answer helped—thank you! I added a fixed width of 580px to the #content div in the example. The max-width does its job, and looks like IE9 wanted the width set first. Other browsers don't like it though, so has to be IE only. http://jsfiddle.net/eyesofjeremy/mKDNn/2/